# Simulate Mouse Movement C#

Tags: c#, controller, cursor, mouse

I'm trying to simulate mouse movement's in C# for games. Like have my code move the mouse to make the game's camera move. This program is suppose to be an adapter to an external controller and I need a joystick to control the move movement.

I've trying using Cursor.Position, but this does nothing more than make the camera in the game spaz out.
What do I do?
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452773.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Anything for C# and will this work in other games?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I just skimmed it without noticing it was in C++. I'm not sure if there is anything for C#, although I'm sure there must be.